# Slide feature and internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on slide feature in my project and I've run into problem on IE 11 that I am having real hard time solving. Everything works fine on chrome, mozilla and edge.

One of the first things that I thought was causing issues is lack CSS prefixes, but after adding them code still didn't work in IE. I have also checked IE 11 support for CSS properties I'm using on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/) website and all properties are supported on IE 11. As far JQ code goes It's pretty straightforward I'm not doing anything special just adding and removing some classes.

Does anyone have idea what might be causing problems and can point me in right direction.

This is my code:

```js
$('#openClose').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('.advanced_search').hasClass('dismiss')) {
    $('.advanced_search').removeClass('dismiss').addClass('selected').show();
  } else {
    $('.advanced_search').removeClass('selected').addClass('dismiss');
  }
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%
}

.advanced_search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #107b10;
  z-index: 999;
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
      transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}

.selected {
  animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
}

.dismiss {
  animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
            transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
            transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-out {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
            transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
            transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-out {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<div class="advanced_search dismiss">
  <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium, quaerat!
  </span>
</div>

<a id="openClose">Open/Close</a>
```

Also here is JSBin with my code so you can quickly do tests: https://jsbin.com/hufodetexa/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Does it work in Edge? Most IE users are using Edge now which also supersede IE. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17454/lifecycle-faq-internet-explorer

Comment: @SimonJensen Yes it works in edge but I need to make it work on IE 11

Comment: I can't test using IE11, but it might be as simple as the missing % sign in the slide-in keyframes block. It should be either a percentage or *from*. Now there's just a zero.

Comment: @Gerard I've tested it right now It's not that, but I will add that to my code just to be safe

Comment: Are you sure you IE 11 is not  in "compatibility mode" and  maybe emulating IE9 or so.. Try adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> to the head of the document to be sure

Comment: @CodeHacker I've tried it, still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added the missing -ms and one missing transform and it works on my ie 11

```js
$('#openClose').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('.advanced_search').hasClass('dismiss')) {
    $('.advanced_search').removeClass('dismiss').addClass('selected').show();
  } else {
    $('.advanced_search').removeClass('selected').addClass('dismiss');
  }
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%
}

.advanced_search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #107b10;
  z-index: 999;
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.selected {
  -ms-animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
  animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
}

.dismiss {
  -webkit-animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
  -ms-animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
  animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;

}

@keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);

  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
    -transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
            transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
            transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-out {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0%);

            transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
            transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-out {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<div class="advanced_search dismiss">
  <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium, quaerat!
  </span>
</div>

<a id="openClose">Open/Close</a>
```

Comment: It seems that's it I will do some tests but thank you very much and I thought that I've added all prefixes

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 Try also always to put the vendor-specific prefixes  before the normal tag.
HAHAHA: It's the first time in long long time that I used the IE for the Real internet.. but I had to test my answer..

Answer (score 1):

CodeHacker solved your problem very well, so I try to give you a more simple approch to the problem, just so you know: what about use a transition and only one class?

Only a second point of view. Give it a try, if you want, works well also with IE11. ;-)

```js
$('#openClose').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.advanced_search').toggleClass("selected")
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%
}

.advanced_search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform:translateX(100%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
}

.selected {
  transform:translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<div class="advanced_search">
  <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium, quaerat!
  </span>
</div>

<a id="openClose">Open/Close</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for this I will definitely consider implementing this.